# Can't use temp dir

Tags: bash, shell, mktemp

I'm trying to make tmp dir with bash script using that command:

```
mktemp -d /tmp/foo.XXXXXXXXX\r
```

So, as an result a have, for example (with common in the end):

```
/tmp/foo.wGBkCRpYt.
```

But I can't change dir after that from this bash script:

```
cd /tmp/foo.wGBkCRpYt
```

**Answer: No such file or directory**

```
cd /tmp/foo.wGBkCRpYt.
```

**Answer: No such file or directory**

What's wrong I do?

Comment: Why do you have `\r` at the end of the name?

Comment: The `\r` means a literal `r` character, so at the end there should be a `r`, not `.`.

Comment: What result gives ````ls -ldb /tmp/foo*````  ?

Comment: `dir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/foo.XXXXXXXXX\r); cd "$dir"`?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your example ends with `r`, while the rest of your examples end with `.` (dot, period, full stop).  Perhaps if they all matched, it would work.

Tested on Debian 11:

This works for me:

```
$ mktemp -d /tmp/foo.XXXXXXXXX\r
/tmp/foo.HaOsouwEHr
$ cd /tmp/foo.HaOsouwEHr
$ pwd
/tmp/foo.HaOsouwEHr
$
```

This works for me:

```
$ mktemp -d /tmp/foo.XXXXXXXXX.
/tmp/foo.H8ERdkgtV.
$ cd /tmp/foo.H8ERdkgtV.
$ pwd
/tmp/foo.H8ERdkgtV.
$
```